# Remove e-mail address in a String SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a field "E-mailTo".

This field contains a string of e-mail addresses.

Example

```
user1@domain.com; user2@domain.com; user3@domain.com; user4@domain.com; user5@domain.com;
user6@domain.com; user3@domain.com;
user7@domain.com; user4@domain.com;
```

I have a 2nd table with a list of e-mail addresses that need to be removed from all E-mailTo strings.

Example

```
user3@domain.com
user4@domain.com
```

Please can anyone help me achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Neither storing CSV in this way or doing a cleanup of such CSV is well suited for a database.  Consider normalizing your data before bringing it into your database.

Comment: which db you are really using ??

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen, I agree, it isn't easy to interact with but I need to and can't change the structure.

Comment: @scaisEdge SQL Server 10.50.6560.0

Comment: You do realize your SQL Server version is already 2 years out of support, and is now 12 years from first release?

Comment: Sadly I do @Charlieface, sadly I do.

Comment: Then it's long past time you address that problem and get to a supported version, @20113hz .

Comment: Can you update your answer with any solutions you have tried? It's okay if they didn't work; they help others narrow their approach or guide you to a better one.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using a replace with join

```
select  replace(a.my_string,  my_table2.col_mail_to_exclude,'')
from my_table1 
inner join my_table2 on my_table1.my_string like concat('%', my_table2.col_mail_to_exclude, '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, it is better to go for normalized design, instead of storing emails as multivalued data.

But, for your needs, You can use recursive CTE to achieve this.

```sql
DECLARE @table1 table(id int, Emailto VARCHAR(8000))
INSERT INTO @table1 values
(1, 'user1@domain.com; user2@domain.com; user3@domain.com; user4@domain.com; user5@domain.com')
,(2, 'user6@domain.com; user3@domain.com;')
,(3,'user7@domain.com; user4@domain.com;')

DECLARE @table2 table(EmailToremove VARCHAR(8000))
INSERT INTO @table2 values
('user3@domain.com'),('user4@domain.com');

;WITH cte_table2rank AS
(
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EmailToRemove) as rnk, EmailToRemove
FROM @table2
), CTE_Cleanser AS
(
select id, EmailTo, 1 as rnk from @table1
UNION ALL
select c2.id, REPLACE(c2.EmailTo,c1.emailtoRemove,'') as Emailto, c2.rnk+1 as rnk
FROM cte_table2rank as C1
inner join CTE_Cleanser as c2
on c2.rnk = c1.rnk
)
SELECT id,Emailto FROM cte_cleanser as oc
where rnk = (SELECT max(rnk) FROM CTE_Cleanser where id = oc.id)
order by id
```

| id | Emailto |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | user1@domain.com; user2@domain.com; ; ; user5@domain.com |
| 2 | user6@domain.com; ; |
| 3 | user7@domain.com; ; |